# Invalid arguments passed to implode when using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to make a library management system.

I transfered data from jquery to php with this line:

```
var jsonString=JSON.stringify(txtvalue);
```

I have decoded data like this:

```
$data=json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']),true);
```

I have imploded data:

```
$imploded_data=implode(',',$data);
```

Now I want to use that data in sql query:

```
$sql_stergere="DELETE FROM carte WHERE titlu IN '{$imploded_data}'";
```

But thid does not work!
Can someone help me?

The error is:"Invalid arguments passed to implode function";

Comment: `stripslashes($_POST['data'])` - why use `stripslashes`?

Comment: So what is `$imploded_data` now?

Comment: Second - __debug__ your code. Third - `WHERE IN ()` uses `()`.

Comment: I have transfered the jsonString to php like this with ajax:data:{data:jsonString}

Comment: According to the error you received `$data` is not a valid array. Check what it actually is by `var_dump($data)`ing it or checking it using [`is_array($data)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php). Most likely your JSON (from javascript) is incorrectly formatted which causes `json_decode()` to return an invalid array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`implode` expects your `$data` to be an array, but you said you are passing in `txtvalue` to `JSON.stringify` in javascript. I believe if you change it to pass an array in javascript that in the first line you should get further (as a comment noted though the SQL may need a change also from {} to ())

If your textValue in javascript is one possible title you want to match I would change your JS to be this so it is a single item in an array. If you have multiple elements you want you will need to put them into a

```
var jsonString=JSON.stringify([txtvalue]);
```